# проблема с фильтром в Bitrix (Битрикс)

Tags: битрикс, битрикс24

Народ, нужда Ваша помощь.
суть какая, на главном сайте отображается количество свободных объектов недвижимости.

есть атрибут выбора статуса (STATUS/XML_ID) в админке (свободна/занято)

на главной странице отображает все объекты вместо того чтобы отображать только доступные.

```
<?
$activeElements = CIBlockSection::GetSectionElementsCount(12, Array("CNT_ACTIVE"=>"Y"));
echo $activeElements;
?>
```

как правильно применить фильтр, чтобы отображало только доступные объекты учитывая XML_ID статус.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что под атрибутом STATUS/XML_ID Вы подразумеваете свойство инфоблока?
Если это так, то попробуете воспользоваться [CIBlockElement::GetList](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/classes/ciblockelement/getlist.php) и прописать в arFilter условие для этого свойства.